# Showing contact name and no. from address book, throwing exception NSInvalidArgumentException

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, ios6, xcode4.5

I'm retrieving Contact name and phone no. from the Address book in my application. I'm printing them in log and it is working fine. But when I try to show them on the table view, I'm getting the exception NSInvalidArgumentException. I have a button on the view controller, pressing which the table view should get populated with the contact names and their no.s:

```
- (IBAction)syncContacts:(id)sender
{
    ABAddressBookRef addressBook = ABAddressBookCreate();
    CFArrayRef allPeople = ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllPeople(addressBook);
    for (int i = 0; i < ABAddressBookGetPersonCount(addressBook); i++) {
        ABRecordRef ref = CFArrayGetValueAtIndex(allPeople, i);

        NSString *contact = (NSString *)CFBridgingRelease(ABRecordCopyCompositeName(ref));

       // NSString* phone = nil;

        ABMultiValueRef phoneNumbers = ABRecordCopyValue(ref,kABPersonPhoneProperty);

      //  if (ABMultiValueGetCount(phoneNumbers) > 0) {

        NSString *phone = (__bridge_transfer NSString*)
            ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(phoneNumbers, 0);

      //  }
        NSDictionary *curContact=[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:(NSString *)contact,@"Name",phone,@"phone",nil];

        [self.phoneContacts addObject:curContact];
    }

    tableView.delegate = self;
    tableView.dataSource = self;
    [tableView reloadData];


    NSLog(@"%@",self.phoneContacts);

    NSLog(@"%i",[self.phoneContacts count]);




}
```

And the table view methods are:

```
-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [self.phoneContacts count];
}
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView   dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
    }

   // cell.textLabel.text = [self.phoneContacts objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];


    cell = [self.phoneContacts objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    return cell;


}
```

What's wrong with the table view? When the phoneContacts had only the name, it was working fine.([phoneContacts addObject:contact]). But now when I'm adding the dictionary object, it is throwing this exception.

I've made a change.

```
 cell = [[self.phoneContacts objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"AddressBook"];
```

The exception doesn't come now. But nothing is getting shown on screen.

Here's the edited method:

```
- (IBAction)syncContacts:(id)sender
{
    ABAddressBookRef addressBook = ABAddressBookCreate();
    CFArrayRef allPeople = ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllPeople(addressBook);
    for (int i = 0; i < ABAddressBookGetPersonCount(addressBook); i++) {
        ABRecordRef ref = CFArrayGetValueAtIndex(allPeople, i);
       // NSNumber *contact = (NSNumber *)ABRecordCopyComposite();// (ref));
        NSString *contact = (NSString *)CFBridgingRelease(ABRecordCopyCompositeName(ref));

       // NSString* phone = nil;

        ABMultiValueRef phoneNumbers = ABRecordCopyValue(ref,kABPersonPhoneProperty);

      //  if (ABMultiValueGetCount(phoneNumbers) > 0) {

        NSString *phone = (__bridge_transfer NSString*)
            ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(phoneNumbers, 0);

      //  }
      //  NSDictionary *curContact=[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:(NSString *)contact,@"Name",phone,@"phone",nil];

        contact = [contact stringByAppendingString:@"     "];
        contact = [contact stringByAppendingString:phone];
        [self.phoneContacts addObject:contact];
    }

    tableView.delegate = self;
    tableView.dataSource = self;
    [tableView reloadData];
}
```

The table view remains unchanged as given in the original post. It is now working.

Comment: The phone numbers (personal, work...) and email addresses (personal, work...) are arrays, not strings.

Comment: yes they're multivalued. But I'm extracting only a single phone number for each contact and assigning that to a string. Printing that string on console is working ok..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The commented line `cell.textLabel.text = [self.phoneContacts objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];` doesn't work? Can you set breakpoint and check if the cell's textlabel have the text assigned?

Assigning the cell using 
`cell = [[self.phoneContacts objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"AddressBook"]`
wouldn't work, unless you defined phoneContacts to be subclass of `UITableViewCell`.

Comment: the commented part gives only the contact name and that too if [phoneContacts addObject:contact] is executed instead of [phoneContacts addObject:curContact]. I don't understand how I can make phoneContacts a subclass of UITableViewCell... sorry I'm new..

Comment: You should handle your array to get a `NSString` containing the Contacts name & NO., by using `[NSString stringWithFormat]` or `[NSString stringByAppendingString]` etc, then set your cell.textLabel.text to that NSString. Don't do cell==xxx...

You could also have multiple textfields in a cell to display different infomation, for example 1 textfield to display name and another to display number.

Comment: I wish I could upvote the comment above... thanks a ton!! n yes, I had changed cell= xx to cell.textlabel.text=xxx, but it strill wasn't working, until I just appended the string.. :)

Comment: Glad it helped! 
Assigning a cell should only be done like `UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView   dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
    }`, which you did correctly :)